# Javascript code not properly work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, background-image

```
<body>
    <a href="link" id="left-link" style="position: fixed; width:0px; height: 100%; "></a>`
    <a href="link" id="right-link" style="position: fixed; width: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; "></a>
    <div id="page-wrap"> .... </div>

    <script>
        (function ($) {
            jQuery(window).resize(function () {
                var width = jQuery('#page-wrap').css('margin-left');
                jQuery('#left-link').css({ width: width });
                jQuery('#right-link').css({ width: width });
            });

            var width = jQuery('#page-wrap').css('margin-left');
            jQuery('#left-link').css({ width: width });
            jQuery('#right-link').css({ width: width });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
```

and I create this script but don't play in Firefox and I cannot find the bug . Chrome and IE play correct .

Comment: A note: the point of `(function($){ ... })(jQuery)` is so that you can use `$` in place of `jQuery` within the `{...}`

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Could it be that the DOM isn't ready when you do the initial assignments? What value do you get in `width`?

Comment: at chrome and at ie width change from 0px to other numbers according the width of page . In firefox width dont change !

Comment: You are aware that in your code you use `margin-left`? I don't see why the margin-left would change?

Comment: I tried the fiddle sra did, in both Chrome, Firefox and IE. I also put it locally on my computer to rule out the iframe on the fiddle. The `margin-left` is always 0px. It looks the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

What is it then that doesn't work?

Is it the code that is supposed to be executed on resize? Test it by using breakpoints in firebug or just print something to the console. Btw. you could make it look better by writing it like this

```
$(window).on("resize", function() { /* your stuff here */ });
```

or does it fail to adjust the width of the two elements you're trying to manipulate? In this case you should take a closer look at what value your width variable holds, maybe it is somehow computed in firefox.

Comment: at chrome and at ie width change from 0px to other numbers according the width of page . In firefox width dont change and i cannot find the bug